# Slow performance of GeoServer WMS with Openlayers + OSM Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, openlayers, postgis, openstreetmap, geoserver

I am new to GIS, and attempting to create a map with **postgresql/postgis**,**geoserver**, **openlayers**, and **osm data**.

I am only serving the NA continent, but it is taking approximately 20 seconds to render the entire map at zoom level 2 (with only roads, boundaries and land use attributes), which is too long for use.

My DB specs are as follows:

| Type | Provider | Version | RAM | VCPU | Storage | Storage Type | Prov. IOPS | Storage Throughput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Postgresql | AWS RDS | 13.7 | 128GB | 16 | 2TB | gp3 SSD | 12,000 | 500 Mibps |

I have tuned the db to these specs:

| Shared Buffers | Work Mem | Main. Work Mem | AutoVac Work Mem | Checkpt Timeout | Max Wal Size | Checkpt Completion Target | Max Wal Senders | Random Page Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 MB | 3 GB | 10 GB | 2GB | 60 Min | 10GB | 0.9 | 5 | 1.0 |

There is only 1 user for this map service so far, and the DB cpu utilization never goes above *20%* . So, I don't think the DB is the problem, but please check my settings.

I have **Geoserver** running in a docker container on an **ECS** cluster, with a t3.2xlarge instance featuring *32.0 GB* RAM and *8 vCPU*. These are my configured Geoserver settings:

*DataStore*
[image]

*Server status*
[image]

*System Status*
[image]
[image]

Geoserver doesn't seem to be using much of its allocated CPU **or** RAM.

My frontend is a small cluster that runs this openlayers code:

```
        let extent: Ext.Extent
        let locations_layer: VectorLayer<VectorSource<Geometry>>
        if (location_list.length > 0) {
            console.log(bbox)
            extent = createExtentFromBoundingBox(JSON.parse(bbox))
            console.log(extent)
            const location_features = createLocationFeatures(JSON.parse(location_list));
            console.log(location_features)
            const locations_source = new VectorSource({ features: location_features });
            locations_layer = new VectorLayer({ source: locations_source });
        } else {
            extent = null

        }
        const view = new View({ center: [0, 0], zoom: 2 });


        const main_roads = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_roads', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        const polygon = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_polygon', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        const supporting_roads = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_line', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        const points = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_point', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        map = new Map({
            target: target,
            view: view,
            layers: [polygon, supporting_roads, main_roads, points]
        })

        view.fit(extent);
    });
```

You can also visit the service here: http://3.19.245.25:8080/

I appreciate any help that anyone might be able to offer, as I have exhausted all of the support material I could find online.

Comment: You might also want to post this here https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Turn logging up to geotools-developer and then check the query that is being made for your map - then add the results of `explain analyze` on that query